# How to find 25 uniformly distributed documents in a geo bounding box?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I have a collection of documents with a location field. I need to find documents within a bounding box, and limit the number of result documents (let's say 25). But I also need these 25 docs were [uniformly distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) all over the bounding box (not just any 25 random docs). Is there any way I can achieve this with MongoDB?

Comment: I think you need to define more clearly what is an _uniform distribution over  ℝ²_ (especially as you are using spherical coordinates here). Is it related to [disk point picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiskPointPicking.html) / [sphere point picking](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) ?

Comment: Did you get the solution for the above mentioned problem?

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of math and thinking then you can get the "nearest" items to the centre of the box. It takes a few operations from the initial query with some help from the aggregation framework.

Lets assume a box of origin (0,0) and a max edge of (4,4), which makes the centre (2,2). Then you would issue the following:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Find results near to the centre of the box
    { "$geoNear": {
        "near": {
            "type": "Point",
            "geometry": [2,2]
        },
        "maxDistance": 4,        // limit a bit outside the boundary
        "distanceField": "dist"  // Projected field with distance
    }},

    // Filter out results outside the box
    { "$match": {
        "$geoWithin": {
            "box": [
                [0,0],
                [4,4]
            ]
        }
    }},

    // Sort by distance
    { "$sort": { "dist": 1 } }

    // Limit the results
    { "$limit": 25 }
])
```

So that's the basic principle. Take note to actually consider what co-ordinate system you are using and whether the data is stored in legacy or GeoJSON format as this affects the distance projected as documented.

But essentially [**`$geoNear`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) finds the features that fall "close to" the centre of the box you later describe. Most importantly it "projects" a field representing the "distance" from the point queried. Then the [**`$geoWithin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/) matches those items that actually fall inside the box.

All that remains is to [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to the nearest entries first, then [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) the total results to a maximum of 25 from the nearest entry first.

Comment: This will not return _"[uniformly distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) documents"_. Or do I missed something ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux  Depends on your definition of how you want to do it. Certainly the `$geoNear` here is going to return you a "distance" from the centre and **that** is the important part, along with then filtering within the bounding box. How you then determine which of those remaining documents to keep by whatever definition you want to do is up to you. So those are the important parts of the answer. If you want "distances" with "sameness" from the centre then you would have to filter the results outside if those first two steps. That seems to be what you are missing.

Comment: I agree that the selection of the _uniformly distributed random documents_ should probably be done at application level. The one thing I didn't understand here was the use of the `$sort` and `$limit` steps. These will only keep the documents close to the center of the bounding box. Quite a biased set, I think.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Which was explained in the opening lines of the answer. The aggregation framework is the **only** method of "chaining" the two required queries ( already stressed as the main point ) but otherwise lacks any further math analysis for the further results or "comparing one against" the other. So I'm focussing on what **can be done** rather than what cannot.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, agreed. If we have to do this calculations at the application level, there is no point of doing '$sort' and '$limit' steps (in this way we'll get points closest to center). The problem of doing this calculations at app level is perfomance (db can return large amount of docs)

Comment: @Leffchik which is why the first two stages "limit" the results themselves. That is the part I don't think you are understanding here. The first two stages are probably what best applies to what you need to do first.

Comment: @user3561036 I understand your answer. The problem is that bounding box can be very large itself in some cases (depends on zoom on map, could be all world for example). That is why even after first two stages db can return big amount of data.

Comment: @Leffchik Tell you what. What exactly do you want from a uniform distribution. The 25 entries closest the mean distance from the centre or what exactly? Explain the precise desired result and I'll show another way of getting there.

Comment: @user3561036 I what this limited number of documents where uniformly spreaded all over bounding box, not concentrated around center, so the user can see, that there is something there (at the corner, for example)

Comment: @Leffchik Okay so your definition here is the 25 data points within the box area that are "least" clustered from other points, right? I'd have to think about the math for that without iteration unless you have a suggested algorithm to be included in the question.

Comment: @user3561036 Yes, I think your definition of problem is pretty close to what I want to achive